# How can I disable single finger double-tap zoom on MPMoviePlayerViewController on iOS?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

When using a MPMoviePlayerViewController, the default behaviours is when you double tap the video with single finger, the video will zoom in a bit.

How can I disable this feature? Because I want double tap to fire a different behaviour other than Zoom in.

Comment: I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like (it works fine for me ! :) ):

```
[[[self.moviePlayer view] subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [[view gestureRecognizers] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id tap, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if([tap isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {

            if([tap numberOfTapsRequired]==2)
            {
                [view removeGestureRecognizer:tap];

            }
        }
    }];
}];
```